# Azure Active Directory graph call trying to access saved token in custom component ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

Azure Active Directory graph call with authorization token trying to access saved token in custom component ASP.NET Core 2.1

If there is more groups then AAD info contains graph api link which I have to call externally using authorization token. Currently I am trying to save token using `options.SaveTokens = true;` in openidconnection options (during startup). I am trying to access saved token in custom components. Do you have any idea how to access it in asp.net core 2.1? [see custom components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

I have used `HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")` approach but it is not working in .NET Core 2.1

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options => {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
        options.SaveTokens = true;
    });
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
}
```

Custom component:

```
public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public ClaimsTransformer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            try
            {
                if (principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
                {
                    string accessToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token"); //Gives stack overflow error
                    string idToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write("Exception", ex);
            }
            return await Task.FromResult(principal);
        }
    }
```